# How can I make this code play the wave file for longer?

Tags: c++, audio, directx, directsound

I couldn't figure out how to create my own sound player, so I have opted to use one from ChiliTomatoNoodle's framework.

The issue I'm having, however, is I have a 180s wave file, that's only playing the first second or so. What do I have to do to make it play longer?

Sound.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <dsound.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class DSound;

class Sound
{
    friend DSound;
public:
    Sound( const Sound& base );
    Sound();
    ~Sound();
    const Sound& operator=( const Sound& rhs );
    void Play( int attenuation = DSBVOLUME_MAX );
private:
    Sound( IDirectSoundBuffer8* pSecondaryBuffer );
private:
    IDirectSoundBuffer8* pBuffer;
};

class DSound
{
private:
    struct WaveHeaderType
    {
        char chunkId[4];
        unsigned long chunkSize;
        char format[4];
        char subChunkId[4];
        unsigned long subChunkSize;
        unsigned short audioFormat;
        unsigned short numChannels;
        unsigned long sampleRate;
        unsigned long bytesPerSecond;
        unsigned short blockAlign;
        unsigned short bitsPerSample;
        char dataChunkId[4];
        unsigned long dataSize;
    };
public:
    DSound( HWND hWnd );
    ~DSound();
    Sound CreateSound( char* wavFileName );
private:
    DSound();
private:    
    IDirectSound8* pDirectSound;
    IDirectSoundBuffer* pPrimaryBuffer;
};
```

Sound.cpp:

```
#include "Sound.h"
#include <assert.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "dsound.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxguid.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib" )

DSound::DSound( HWND hWnd )
: pDirectSound( NULL ),
  pPrimaryBuffer( NULL )
{
    HRESULT result;
    DSBUFFERDESC bufferDesc;
    WAVEFORMATEX waveFormat;

    result = DirectSoundCreate8( NULL,&pDirectSound,NULL );
    assert( !FAILED( result ) );

    // Set the cooperative level to priority so the format of the primary sound buffer can be modified.
    result = pDirectSound->SetCooperativeLevel( hWnd,DSSCL_PRIORITY );
    assert( !FAILED( result ) );

    // Setup the primary buffer description.
    bufferDesc.dwSize = sizeof(DSBUFFERDESC);
    bufferDesc.dwFlags = DSBCAPS_PRIMARYBUFFER | DSBCAPS_CTRLVOLUME;
    bufferDesc.dwBufferBytes = 0;
    bufferDesc.dwReserved = 0;
    bufferDesc.lpwfxFormat = NULL;
    bufferDesc.guid3DAlgorithm = GUID_NULL;

    // Get control of the primary sound buffer on the default sound device.
    result = pDirectSound->CreateSoundBuffer( &bufferDesc,&pPrimaryBuffer,NULL );
    assert( !FAILED( result ) );

    // Setup the format of the primary sound bufffer.
    // In this case it is a .WAV file recorded at 44,100 samples per second in 16-bit stereo (cd audio format).
    waveFormat.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
    waveFormat.nSamplesPerSec = 44100;
    waveFormat.wBitsPerSample = 16;
    waveFormat.nChannels = 2;
    waveFormat.nBlockAlign = (waveFormat.wBitsPerSample / 8) * waveFormat.nChannels;
    waveFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec = waveFormat.nSamplesPerSec * waveFormat.nBlockAlign;
    waveFormat.cbSize = 0;

    // Set the primary buffer to be the wave format specified.
    result = pPrimaryBuffer->SetFormat( &waveFormat );
    assert( !FAILED( result ) );
}

DSound::~DSound()
{
    if( pPrimaryBuffer )
    {
        pPrimaryBuffer->Release();
        pPrimaryBuffer = NULL;
    }
    if( pDirectSound )
    {
        pDirectSound->Release();
        pDirectSound = NULL;
    }
}

// must be 44.1k 16bit Stereo PCM Wave
Sound DSound::CreateSound( char* wavFileName )
{
    int error;
    FILE* filePtr;
    unsigned int count;
    WaveHeaderType waveFileHeader;
    WAVEFORMATEX waveFormat;
    DSBUFFERDESC bufferDesc;
    HRESULT result;
    IDirectSoundBuffer* tempBuffer;
    IDirectSoundBuffer8* pSecondaryBuffer;
    unsigned char* waveData;
    unsigned char* bufferPtr;
    unsigned long bufferSize;


    // Open the wave file in binary.
    error = fopen_s( &filePtr,wavFileName,"rb" );
    assert( error == 0 );

    // Read in the wave file header.
    count = fread( &waveFileHeader,sizeof( waveFileHeader ),1,filePtr );
    assert( count == 1 );

    // Check that the chunk ID is the RIFF format.
    assert( (waveFileHeader.chunkId[0] == 'R') && 
            (waveFileHeader.chunkId[1] == 'I') && 
            (waveFileHeader.chunkId[2] == 'F') && 
            (waveFileHeader.chunkId[3] == 'F') );

    // Check that the file format is the WAVE format.
    assert( (waveFileHeader.format[0] == 'W') && 
            (waveFileHeader.format[1] == 'A') &&
            (waveFileHeader.format[2] == 'V') &&
            (waveFileHeader.format[3] == 'E') );

    // Check that the sub chunk ID is the fmt format.
    assert( (waveFileHeader.subChunkId[0] == 'f') && 
            (waveFileHeader.subChunkId[1] == 'm') &&
            (waveFileHeader.subChunkId[2] == 't') && 
            (waveFileHeader.subChunkId[3] == ' ') );

    // Check that the audio format is WAVE_FORMAT_PCM.
    assert( waveFileHeader.audioFormat == WAVE_FORMAT_PCM );

    // Check that the wave file was recorded in stereo format.
    assert( waveFileHeader.numChannels == 2 );

    // Check that the wave file was recorded at a sample rate of 44.1 KHz.
    assert( waveFileHeader.sampleRate == 44100 );

    // Ensure that the wave file was recorded in 16 bit format.
    assert( waveFileHeader.bitsPerSample == 16 );

    // Check for the data chunk header.
    assert( (waveFileHeader.dataChunkId[0] == 'd') && 
            (waveFileHeader.dataChunkId[1] == 'a') &&
            (waveFileHeader.dataChunkId[2] == 't') &&
            (waveFileHeader.dataChunkId[3] == 'a') );

    // Set the wave format of secondary buffer that this wave file will be loaded onto.
    waveFormat.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
    waveFormat.nSamplesPerSec = 44100;
    waveFormat.wBitsPerSample = 16;
    waveFormat.nChannels = 2;
    waveFormat.nBlockAlign = (waveFormat.wBitsPerSample / 8) * waveFormat.nChannels;
    waveFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec = waveFormat.nSamplesPerSec * waveFormat.nBlockAlign;
    waveFormat.cbSize = 0;

    // Set the buffer description of the secondary sound buffer that the wave file will be loaded onto.
    bufferDesc.dwSize = sizeof(DSBUFFERDESC);
    bufferDesc.dwFlags = DSBCAPS_CTRLVOLUME;
    bufferDesc.dwBufferBytes = waveFileHeader.dataSize;
    bufferDesc.dwReserved = 0;
    bufferDesc.lpwfxFormat = &waveFormat;
    bufferDesc.guid3DAlgorithm = GUID_NULL;

    // Create a temporary sound buffer with the specific buffer settings.
    result = pDirectSound->CreateSoundBuffer( &bufferDesc,&tempBuffer,NULL );
    assert( !FAILED( result ) );

    // Test the buffer format against the direct sound 8 interface and create the secondary buffer.
    result = tempBuffer->QueryInterface( IID_IDirectSoundBuffer8,(void**)&pSecondaryBuffer );
    assert( !FAILED( result ) );

    // Release the temporary buffer.
    tempBuffer->Release();
    tempBuffer = 0;

    // Move to the beginning of the wave data which starts at the end of the data chunk header.
    fseek( filePtr,sizeof(WaveHeaderType),SEEK_SET );

    // Create a temporary buffer to hold the wave file data.
    waveData = new unsigned char[ waveFileHeader.dataSize ];
    assert( waveData );

    // Read in the wave file data into the newly created buffer.
    count = fread( waveData,1,waveFileHeader.dataSize,filePtr );
    assert( count == waveFileHeader.dataSize);

    // Close the file once done reading.
    error = fclose( filePtr );
    assert( error == 0 );

    // Lock the secondary buffer to write wave data into it.
    result = pSecondaryBuffer->Lock( 0,waveFileHeader.dataSize,(void**)&bufferPtr,(DWORD*)&bufferSize,NULL,0,0 );
    assert( !FAILED( result ) );

    // Copy the wave data into the buffer.
    memcpy( bufferPtr,waveData,waveFileHeader.dataSize );

    // Unlock the secondary buffer after the data has been written to it.
    result = pSecondaryBuffer->Unlock( (void*)bufferPtr,bufferSize,NULL,0 );
    assert( !FAILED( result ) );

    // Release the wave data since it was copied into the secondary buffer.
    delete [] waveData;
    waveData = NULL;

    return Sound( pSecondaryBuffer );
}

Sound::Sound( IDirectSoundBuffer8* pSecondaryBuffer )
: pBuffer( pSecondaryBuffer )
{}

Sound::Sound()
: pBuffer( NULL )
{}

Sound::Sound( const Sound& base )
: pBuffer( base.pBuffer )
{
    pBuffer->AddRef();
}

Sound::~Sound()
{
    if( pBuffer )
    {
        pBuffer->Release();
        pBuffer = NULL;
    }
}

const Sound& Sound::operator=( const Sound& rhs )
{
    this->~Sound();
    pBuffer = rhs.pBuffer;
    pBuffer->AddRef();
    return rhs;
}

// attn is the attenuation value in units of 0.01 dB (larger 
// negative numbers give a quieter sound, 0 for full volume)
void Sound::Play( int attn )
{
    attn = max( attn,DSBVOLUME_MIN );
    HRESULT result;

    // check that we have a valid buffer
    assert( pBuffer != NULL );

    // Set position at the beginning of the sound buffer.
    result = pBuffer->SetCurrentPosition( 0 );
    assert( !FAILED( result ) );

    // Set volume of the buffer to attn
    result = pBuffer->SetVolume( attn );
    assert( !FAILED( result ) );

    // Play the contents of the secondary sound buffer.
    result = pBuffer->Play( 0,0,0 );
    assert( !FAILED( result ) );
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Do you mean playing the sound in a loop? Then set the `Looping` flag in the `Play` call.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a .wav file, and you are loading the sound file somewhere along the lines of:

```
yourSound = audio.CreateSound("fileName.WAV"); //Capslock on WAV
yourSound.Play();
```

With this comes the declaration of the Sound in the header:

```
Sound yourSound;
```

Now because you have probably done this already and this is not working it likely has to do with your file as playing sounds 160 seconds+ should not be a problem.

Are you using a .WAV file for the sound? If so did you happen to convert that (as it is probably a background sound?). If you did try converting it with this converter:

[Converter MP3 -> WAV](http://www.mp3cutter.in/convert/mp3-to-wav/)

Please let me know if this works!

Answer (score 0):

Your buffer is probably only large enough to play the first second or so. What you need to do is setup "notifications". See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418746%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Notifications are a way to ask the audio hardware to let you know when they have reached a specific point in the buffer.

The idea is to setup a notification in the middle of the buffer and at the end of the buffer. When you receive the notification from the notification in the middle, you fill the first half of the buffer with more data. When you receive the notification from the end, you fill the second half of the buffer with more data. This way, you can stream an infinite amount of data with a single buffer.